# How to make the UltragridColumn Style URL editable

Tags: vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have a `Ultragrid` which has a column style as URL. This column in default is readonly which is grey in color. Now I have to make this column as editable. I tried like changing the column style when it is URL. But it doesn't work.

//Code:

```
If (CType(Field.FieldTypeId, ColumnStyle) = ColumnStyle.URL) Then
         UltraGridColumn.Style = ColumnStyle.Default
Else
         UltraGridColumn.Style = CType(Field.FieldTypeId, ColumnStyle)
End If
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an UltraGridColumn editable depends on numerous properities.

First and foremost, the UltraGrid should allow updating. This is controlled by the property

```
grid.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowUpdate = DefaultableBoolean.True
```

with this property you allow the entire grid to be updated (you can limit this applying the same property but at the Bands level). However this is not enough to enable editing because you need to set (for the individuals columns) two other properties

```
column.CellActivation = Activation.AllowEdit
column.CellClickAction = CellClickAction.Edit
```

However, I have made some research on the URL style. It seems that this style assigns to your columns a `FormattedLinkEditor` object that doesn't allow the link text to be edited in any way (It is considered a label). So I suggest, unless someone from Infragistics has a better recommendation,  to use a normal edit column. (Of course, if your intention is only to edit the link text)

This short example captures the click on the cell and tries to start an editing session, but with no success

```
    private void ultraGrid1_InitializeLayout(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
    {
        UltraGridColumn cc = e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns[0];
        cc.Style = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.URL;
        (cc.Editor as FormattedLinkEditor).LinkClicked += Form1_LinkClicked;
        cc.CellActivation = Activation.AllowEdit;
        cc.CellClickAction = CellClickAction.EditAndSelectText;
        cc.Width = 500;
    }

    void Form1_LinkClicked(object sender, Infragistics.Win.FormattedLinkLabel.LinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.OpenLink = false;
        ultraGrid1.PerformAction(UltraGridAction.EnterEditMode);
    }
```

Comment: Steve: It works for all except the column having the style as URL. Can you help me in this?

Comment: I have tested the URL style and effectively it is readonly. I will try to investigate it time permitting

Comment: Check if this link is of any help http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/54671.aspx

Comment: Thanks Steve. Kindly look and let me know if it is possible. Can u look into this ques? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17943824/show-calendar-in-ultragrid-column-filter

Comment: Did u had a look into this ques? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17943824/show-calendar-in-ultragrid-column-filter.

Comment: Made some research on the URL style. It seems that this style assigns to your columns the `FormattedLinkEditor` that against all my tries doesn't allow the link text to be edited in any way (It is considered a label). So I give up, unless someone from Infragistics has a better recommendation, I suggest you to use a normal edit column if your intention is only to edit the text portion on the link

Comment: Many thanks for your time. Can look into the question that I have asked here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17943824/show-calendar-in-ultragrid-column-filter.

Comment: I didn't notice the grid column is overrided in the code at the end. So now it works fine. Thanks.